# Analog long duration timer (5 minutes) using a ramp

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, ramp-generator

I am trying to make a timer with a period of about 5 min. The problem with such a slow ramp (with high impedance) is in triggering the next circuit like a latch or monostable to get a useful output signal. The ramp has such a slow dV/dt rate that exteme gain is needed in the sensing circuit.

Even with the gain of two transistors, the triggering isn't very clear and the latch will take a time to change state.

One thing I can imagine is in trying to fire a monostable in about 1 second intervals using short pulses generated from another oscillator. If the ramp voltage is high enough AND a short pulse  comes, then the monostable will flip.

The reason for this is that the monostable has an advantage: it will return to a stable state if the triggering pulse is in metastability level and regeneratr itself to be ready for next triggering pulse (when the ramp will have a higher voltage) and do a sucessful flip.

Does anyone have a better solution?

[image]

[image]

Here the timer period is lower (10s) to avoid high simulation times.
Green is ramp (C6 voltage), red are short pulses, blue is monostable output what discharges the C6 capacitor.

Comment: If you have a source of pulses, why not do the rest with a digital counter?

Comment: The "better solution" is a digital solution. A microcontroller would be smaller and cheaper.

Comment: Using the counter to avoid high time contants make sense of course, but I want to use this ramp in next analog circuitry what would lead to D/A conversion. Also I met this kind of problem in more situations where signals changes too slow (batteries, sensors, fluctuating voltages) and catching a tresholds is needed.

Comment: You really should have been more clear when you asked the original question. You said you **needed** a timer, not a ramp voltage.

Comment: That was the exact reason for inventing the 555 timer, probably! Either an MCU or an actual 555 (556 for the combo pack) would be better than doing it in discretes; BTW, if you are doing it in analog try changing the trigger topology to a differential amp and a reference

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a simpler circuit, but really the problem is that getting a linear ramp from an analog circuit that is 5 minutes long and has any kind of accuracy is not so easy. You show a 200uF capacitor. Calculate the leakage of that capacitor based on datasheet values, for example. Anyway, assuming an ideal capacitor, here is one way to do it. I've used a 10-cent LM324 (leaving one amplifier free) and a couple MOSFET transistors. BJTs would work about as well. I've used one of the op-amps as a comparator which is fine in this case, but caution is required if you want to substitute a "better" op-amp. You can find many ideas and opinions elsewhere here on the wisdom of using op-amps as comparators.

[image]

[image]

This circuit uses a constant current of about 4uA to create the ramp, which is buffered by an op-amp and compared to a 6V reference created by R2/R3/R4 chain and the supply voltage. R5 and C2 stretches the reset pulse out via positive feedback to completely reset C1.

To do this for real, a small 8-bit MCU would be infinitely better, and if you really need that ramp, use a DAC to generate a precise linear digitally-timed ramp that will likely need no calibration, and will not drift significantly with time or temperature- in comparison with a drifty analog circuit that will not be very accurate to begin with, and won't hold whatever trimming you do to it.